# SQL Server : How to subtract values throughout the rows by using values in another column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `stock` and `sales` as below :

Stock Table :

```
+--------+----------+---------+
| Stk_ID | Stk_Name | Stk_Qty |
+--------+----------+---------+
| 1001   | A        | 20      |
| 1002   | B        | 50      |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

Sales Table :

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Sales_ID | Sales_Date | Sales_Item | Sales_Qty |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2001     | 2016-07-15 | A          | 5         |
| 2002     | 2016-07-20 | B          | 7         |
| 2003     | 2016-07-23 | A          | 4         |
| 2004     | 2016-07-29 | A          | 2         |
| 2005     | 2016-08-03 | B          | 15        |
| 2006     | 2016-08-07 | B          | 10        |
| 2007     | 2016-08-10 | A          | 5         |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

With the table above, how can I find the available stock `Ava_Stk` for each stock after every sales?
**`Ava_Stk` is expected to subtract `Sales_Qty` from `Stk_Qty` after every sales.**

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+
| Sales_ID | Sales_Date | Sales_Item | Sales_Qty | Ava_Stk |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 2001     | 2016-07-15 | A          | 5         | 15      |
| 2002     | 2016-07-20 | B          | 7         | 43      |
| 2003     | 2016-07-23 | A          | 4         | 11      |
| 2004     | 2016-07-29 | A          | 2         | 9       |
| 2005     | 2016-08-03 | B          | 15        | 28      |
| 2006     | 2016-08-07 | B          | 10        | 18      |
| 2007     | 2016-08-10 | A          | 5         | 4       |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: Call me crazy but are you joining the stock on the sale item based on stk_name=sales_item?

Comment: Yeah... better schema would really put the Stk_ID in the sales table.

Answer (score 1):

You want a cumulative sum and to subtract it from the stock table.  In SQL Server 2012+:

```
select s.*,
       (st.stk_qty -
        sum(s.sales_qty) over (partition by s.sales_item order by sales_date)
       ) as ava_stk
from sales s join
     stock st
     on s.sales_item = st.stk_name;
```